# How to find the bit of code that causes involuntary routing? (in a legacy website)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, legacy-code

Please help me, I am working on reusing an old AngularJS based website and I keep encountering unexpected events of routing caused by unknown code.

When I press various elements on the site none of which have apparent event handlers 
with such code, the routing leads to a "page-not-found" page as expected.

I have already put breakpoints around all the references of "$location" and "$route". and I have looked up all the "href" attributes in the code
and I did not find anything suspicious.

When I have put a break-point inside a '$routeChangeStart' hook as follows

```
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {

    debugger;
    //.....
}
```

I have got the following objects:

```
    next = { 
            params: {}
            pathParams: {} 
           }
```

(without "$$route" )

```
event = {
   currentScope: m {$id: 2, $$childTail: m, $$childHead: m, $$prevSibling: null, 
   $$nextSibling: null, …}
   defaultPrevented: false
   name: "$routeChangeStart"
   preventDefault: ƒ ()
   targetScope: m {$id: 2, $$childTail: m, $$childHead: m, $$prevSibling: null, 
   $$nextSibling: null, …}
}
```

(targetScope==currentScope) is true

the project also uses Kendo and JQuery

I do realize that I cannot expect any specific answer but any advice will be welcome.

Where I should be looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I had to do is to check the call-stack in the debugger stopping on the break-point in

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart' ...
```

pathParams was empty because the route was invalid.